# What to do when my Terminal is stuck at node app.js in Mongoose session?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a MongoDB course. The instructor was teaching how to use and require mongoose in app.js file. After requiring mongoose in app.js, I was instructed to run the command in terminal

```
$ node app.js
```

But the terminal get stuck & gets stuck forever. The screenshot of the terminal:

[image]

Here is the code of app.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB");
```

Please Help!

Comment: what do you expect the terminal to do, other than print nothing? Your code does nothing other than connect to a DB

Answer (score 3):

Your app is not stuck, after mongoose connects, the connection keeps your app alive until you disconnect with `mongoose.disconnect()` or until something else closes (or crashes) the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and you can see the dollar sign.